# Maven dependencies are added automatically to my pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

Is it possible that my pom.xml adds by himself dependencies and exclusions ?

For example : almost this part was been added automatically !!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea ? thanks

Comment: It's really disappointing but nothing ever happens "by itself". Something _must_ have happened for those dependencies to be included.

Comment: Yes i'm sure , but what does things happen !! it is really weird  !!

Comment: After which action do you recognize this having been added? Is it maybe after getting the latest revision from an SCM?

Comment: @Tunaki Admitted, it's a long time ago (and a bit OT here), but there is something that happened by itself, without a reason: the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang). :-)

Comment: I'm using INtelliJ, and Any time I do a revert to a past GIT commit version .. I see in the Annotations like if I added new dependencies .. and the dependencies added are not formatted (like if a Robot have added them): 
here is a screenshot : 
http://snag.gy/AHIER.jpg

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that the `pom.xml` included in this "_past GIT commit_" didn't contain these dependency declarations?

Comment: I hope that I'm wrong .... but, yes I'm sure :( because I ve going back to a version dated one year before ... and I was not working yet in the company ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89428/discussion-between-taboubim-and-gerold-broser).

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but no, I decided to deliberately ignore patronizing messages generated automatically a long time ago.

Comment: Do you think IntelliJ is updating the pom.xml by him self ? because I remember IntelliJ asked me to resolve some issues by adding maven dependencies
Also for your information, I'm using a parent pom and a dependencyManagement ... thanks

Comment: which message generated automatically ? if you mean this one ( **Let us continue this discussion in chat** ), it is generated by Stackoverflow because he said that there is lot of comments lets talks in a private room ...  ( I'm sorry I'm a new user :) )

Comment: That seems to be the answer: _"IntelliJ asked me to resolve some issues by adding maven dependencies"_. I can't tell if it actually is. I don't use IntelliJ. Yes, I meant this message but it wasn't meant being against you. So, there's nothing to be sorry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer of my question is that IDEA IntelliJ is adding the dependencies to my `pom.xml`.

**Intellij asked me in the past to authorize it to update the dependencies automatically** and I've agreed.

So thanks to every one helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a feature called 'Transitive Dependencies'. When an application has a dependency that has it's own dependencies, Maven will add those dependencies to your project automatically. You can read more about transitive dependencies on the Maven website [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is talking about transitive dependencies. Looks like part of his pom was "generated".

Comment: @Tunaki I believe transitive dependencies are included in the Effective POM

Comment: In the effective pom, yes, but I don't think OP is not talking about the effective pom.

Comment: Do you think that : if a .jar exist in my .m2 maven repository, the pom.xml will be readjusted by adding dependencies ??

Comment: @taboubim No, I don't think that any of the other commenters thinks so. I've never experienced such a behaviour in years of working with Maven.

Comment: @cbender: Transitive dependencies are not included in the effective POM. The only additional dependencies that may appear in the effective POM are the dependencies inherited from the parent POM.